# Does toPandas() speed up as a pyspark dataframe gets smaller?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I figured I would ask the question. I've found a clever way to reduce the size of a PySpark Dataframe and convert it to Pandas and I was just wondering, does the toPandas function get faster as the size of the pyspark dataframe gets smaller? Here is some code:

```
window = Window.partitionBy(F.lit('A')).orderBy(F.lit('A'))

eps_tfs = {}
while True:
    pdf = toPandas(conn.select(F.col('*')).where(F.col('row_number') <= 2500))
    n = len(pdf)
    trigger = 0
    for u in pdf['features']:
        indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(u) if x == 1.0]
        for idx in range(len(eps_columns)):
            if idx in indices:
                try:
                    eps_tfs[eps_columns[idx]].append(True)
                except:
                    eps_tfs[eps_columns[idx]] = [True]
            else:
                try:
                    eps_tfs[eps_columns[idx]].append(False)
                except:
                    eps_tfs[eps_columns[idx]] = [False]
    full_view = full_view.append(pd.concat([pdf, pd.DataFrame(eps_tfs)], axis=1))
    conn = conn.select(F.col('*')).where(F.col('row_number') > 2500)
    conn = conn.drop("row_number")
    conn = conn.select(F.col('*'), F.row_number().over(window).alias('row_number'))
    eps_tfs = {}
    del pdf
    if n < 2500:
        break
```

Also, is the following code really a faster way to map the dataframe to pandas?

```
def _map_to_pandas(rdds):
    """ Needs to be here due to pickling issues """
    return [pd.DataFrame(list(rdds))]

def toPandas(df, n_partitions=None):
    """
    Returns the contents of `df` as a local `pandas.DataFrame` in a speedy fashion. The DataFrame is
    repartitioned if `n_partitions` is passed.
    :param df:              pyspark.sql.DataFrame
    :param n_partitions:    int or None
    :return:                pandas.DataFrame
    """
    if n_partitions is not None: df = df.repartition(n_partitions)
    df_pand = df.rdd.mapPartitions(_map_to_pandas).collect()
    df_pand = pd.concat(df_pand)
    df_pand.columns = df.columns
    return df_pand
```

Is there any better way to go about doing this?

Comment: I would ask different question here - will ```pandas``` be more appropriate to your use case than ```pyspark``` if so - why not do everything in ```pandas```, if not - why converting?

Comment: I tried the last piece of code for my use case (98 PySpark Dataframes of approx. 4K rows each to convert into Pandas Dataframe), it took around **14min**, versus only around **6min** via **toPandas()** PySpark function (both tested on the same config., of course).

Conclusion: definitely not speeding up conversion of small dataframes !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.toPandas) is the source code to ToPandas,

And first of all, yes, toPandas will be faster if your pyspark dataframe gets smaller, it has similar taste as sdf.collect()
The difference is ToPandas return a pdf and collect return a list.
As you can see from the source code `pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(self.collect(), columns=self.columns)` pdf is generated from pd.DataFrame.from_records from the List!

So if your sdf is smaller, there a smaller data to be transferred through the network, and `from_record` process less data using your Driver's CPU.

The Design of the second code is different, sdf is distributed, code calls a Mappartition so all worker generates a Pandas dataframe from the subset of the data, then it calls collect, now the all the Pandas dataframe transferred through the network, brought to the driver. Then code calls pd.concat to concat all the dataframe together.

The benefits are:

1. When converting to Pandas DataFrame, all the workers work on a small subset of the data in parallel much better than bring all data to the driver and burn your driver's CPU to convert a giant data to Pandas.
2. There is a repartition going on, means if your dataset is huge, and you have a low number of partition, the data on each partition will be huge, and toPandas will be failed on OOM of serializer, and also very slow to collect the data

The Drawbacks are:

1. now when you collect, you are not collecting the native sdf data, instead of a pandas dataframe which have more metadata attached and generally larger, means the total size of object are bigger
2. `pd.concat` is slow lol, but might still better than `from_record`

So there is no universal conclusion saying which method is better, but choose wisely which tool to use. Like in this question, toPandas might be faster than small sdf, but for large size sdf, the code snippet definitively works better.

Comment: I think the source code for "toPandas" should be: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html

Answer (score 4):

In our case, we found that just not doing `toPandas()` and using `pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(self.collect(), columns=self.columns)` was fastest.  We couldn't use the `arrow` option because we got the error "arrow is not supported when using file-based collect".

Looking at the source code for `toPandas()`, one reason it may be slow is because it first creates the pandas `DataFrame`, and then copies each of the `Series` in that `DataFrame` over to the returned `DataFrame`.  If you know that all of your columns have unique names, and that the data types will convert nicely via having pandas infer the `dtype` values, there is no need to do any of that copying or dtype inference.

Side note:  We were converting a Spark DataFrame on Databricks with about 2 million rows and 6 columns, so your mileage may vary dependent on the size of your conversion.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @EZY is true (that you need to collect all rows to the driver or client). However, there is one more optimisation possible with apache arrow [integration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/arrow_pandas.html). It provides faster libraries for numpy and pandas data types. It's not enabled by default, so you need to enable it by setting spark conf like below.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
```